# Print hash table as literal

Tags: powershell

Let's say I have a hash table in a variable:

```
$tbl = @{ abc = 100; def = 200 }
```

Is there a way to print it out such that it's a valid PowerShell hash table literal?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple function to handle hashtables like that given in the example:

```powershell
function HashtableToString( $h ) {
  $items = @($h.GetEnumerator() | foreach { '{0} = {1}' -f $_.Key,$_.Value })
  '@{ ' + ($items -join '; ') + ' }'
}
```

Note that this does not handle arbitrary values (e.g. strings used as values would need to be quoted, unlike keys), but numeric values appear correctly.

Answer (score 0):

There is no method to print the hash as literal hash, you have to create your own function to print the hash table.